# Where to find curriculum for a specific program?

Tags: university

I have an assignment for preparing the first draft of curriculum for a new program in my university. To include international experiences, I tried to get the curriculum of other universities, but I was unable to find a university website sharing the full curriculum. Department websites just put the title of courses, and professors post syllabus for their courses.

Each department should have its curriculum (description of the program, courses and credit details, course descriptions, etc), and this should be a public document.

When I searched general or visited top university websites, I expected to find such documents.

Do you have any idea where I can find documented curriculum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At many US institutions I believe what you are looking for is often called a "course catalog". This generally lists degree programs, what courses are required for each major/minor, as well as a description of each course and their associated credit load.

With this phrase in mind a quick Googling returned a variety of listings for top Universities:

[Carnegie Mellon Undergraduate Catalog](http://coursecatalog.web.cmu.edu/)
[MIT Course catalog](http://web.mit.edu/referencepubs/catalog/)
[Undergraduate and Graduate catalogs for University of Wisconsin-Madison](http://www.wisc.edu/academics/catalogs.php)

If that's what you were looking for, just the magic phrase "course catalog" will help in the US. But in other countries? Well, a search for a course catalog for University of Cape Town in South Africa produced a link to the student "[handbooks](https://www.uct.ac.za/students/undergraduates/handbooks/)", which appear to be the same thing as the US course catalog.

It appears each country has their own preferred term for what to call this, so finding the magic words for each country might be a bit of a trick.