# Are there online resources for finding information on M.S. programs that fit my criteria, without having to go through every school's website?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, online-resource

I'm looking for an M.S. in Computer Science and I found it difficult to properly navigate all the available degrees. I'm interested in a particular focus (computer graphics, not modelling and that kind of stuff but how to do use algorithms in order to create graphics). I also have some constraints on language: I currently speak both Dutch and English, so no German or French master's for me.

There are other questions on this site about [finding graduate programs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/methods-for-finding-graduate-programs-for-specific-areas-of-research) and [their curriculums](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19732/where-to-find-curriculum-for-a-specific-program), but I'm mainly looking for quick preselection (like a top 30 of options I have). I'm looking for a overview of courses as it enables quick elimination which if I have to wait for each uni to answer will take quite a long time

Is there any website or other online resource that will allow me to filter all M.S. programs by my requirements (language or country, research focus) and then find out information (such as the list of courses that comprise the degree) about the programs that meet my criteria, all in one place?

Comment: (Edited based on extended discussion in comments, which I have since cleaned up)

Answer (score 2):

The most useful I found (which also helped me finding one for me) is [Find a masters](http://www.findamasters.com/search/courses.aspx?DID=5).

It does let you select a country of your choice, provides a summary of program where courses list, research focus and other things important are mentioned.

It also lets you filter by program type (Dip, Cert or degree), by study plan (part time, full time etc) and more.

Lastly, it also provides a link to university website so you can go there easily for complete details if you like the description.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this site [study in us](http://studyn.us)

They are still in early stages but have most of the information you need.
You can filter the colleges based on your requirements and find more details about each college.